# python boto 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'stop_isntances'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, boto, boto3

i am learning python boto module and i am trying to stop a running instance .

```
import boto.ec2
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-west-2")
conn.stop_instances(instance_ids=['i-0aa5ce441ef7e0e2a'])
```

but i am getting  error which says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'stop_instances'
```

i gave AWS_access keys for boto.

can anyone please help me to fix this error ?

Comment: `conn` is `None` here. According to [the docs](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.connect_to_region), this can happen if the region you specify is invalid. Is this your exact code?

Comment: yes , this my code as i am learning boto . but i have instances running in that region.

Answer (score 0):

As @kindall points out, your `conn` object is not initialized (it's NoneType). I also see that you're using boto in the example, but I thought that I would provide an example of this using boto3:

```
import boto3

boto3_session = boto3.Session(profile=some_profile_you_configured)
boto3_client = boto3_session.client('ec2', region_name='us-west-2')

response = boto3_client.stop_instances(InstanceIds=['i-0aa5ce441ef7e0e2a'])
```